# Using board_create for aruco markers leads to error due to objPoints not in the correct type

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I am trying to reverse engineer an aruco board from detecting it in an image.

I made a snippet to reproduce the same problem when creating the GridBoard and then trying to use create_Board on the detected corners and ids on the created image.

```
# Settings for the marker
max_amount_of_markers_w = 10
max_amount_of_markers_h = 6
ar = aruco.DICT_6X6_1000
aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(ar)

# creat an aruco Board
grid_board = cv2.aruco.GridBoard_create(max_amount_of_markers_w,
                                        max_amount_of_markers_h,
                                        0.05,
                                        0.01,
                                        aruco_dict)

# convert to image
img = grid_board.draw((1920,180))

# detected corners and ids
corners,ids,rejected = aruco.detectMarkers(img,
                                           aruco_dict)

# convert to X,Y,Z
new_corners = np.zeros(shape=(len(corners),4,3))
for cnt,corner in enumerate(corners):
    new_corners[cnt,:,:-1] = corner

# try to create a board via Board_create
aruco.Board_create(new_corners,aruco_dict,ids)
```

The error comes from the last line, the error is the following:

> error: OpenCV(4.1.1)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\aruco\src\aruco.cpp:1458:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) objPoints.type() == CV_32FC3 ||
>   objPoints.type() == CV_32FC1 in function 'cv::aruco::Board::create'

This means that it needs something with 3 channels (for x,y and z) which is given as the numpy array.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but I just came across the same problem, so I'll answer for posterity.

The error is not linked to the number of channels that is correct, but linked to the datatype of `new_corners`, here `new_corners.dtype == np.float64`. But OpenCV asks for a 32-bit float, as your error shows with `CV_32F`.
A simple cast of `new_corners` fixes the issue. Your last line becomes :

`aruco.Board_create(new_corners.astype(np.float32),aruco_dict,ids)`

Comment: Thanks @Jux, your answer really helped me :-)